# Django: get choices key from display value

Tags: django

Let's say I have the following Django model:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        (0, 'Small'),
        (1, 'Medium'),
        (2, 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.IntegerField(choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```

I can create create a `Person` instance and get the shirt_size [display value](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display) very easily:

```
john = Person(name="John", shirt_size=2)
john.shirt_size  # 2
john.get_shirt_size_display()  # 'Medium'
```

How can I do this the other way? That is, given a shirt size of `Medium`, how can I get the integer value? I there a method for that or should I write my own method on the `Person` object like so:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    ...

    @staticmethod
    def get_shirt_size_key_from_display_value(display_value):
    for (key, value) in Person.SHIRT_SIZES:
        if value == display_value:
            return key
        raise ValueError(f"No product type with display value {display_value}")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#choices) recommend the following:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    SMALL = 0
    MEDIUM = 1
    LARGE = 2
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        (SMALL, 'Small'),
        (MEDIUM, 'Medium'),
        (LARGE, 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.IntegerField(choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```

Now the name `MEDIUM` is attached to your model and model instances:

```
>>> john = Person(name="John", shirt_size=2)
>>> john.shirt_size
2
>>> john.MEDIUM
2
```

If given a string, you can use `getattr`:

```
def get_shirt_size(instance, shirt_size):
    return getattr(instance, shirt_size.upper())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
choices_dict = {y: x for x, y in shirt_size.choices}
```

will give you a dictionary with all the ints as values and sizes as keys.

So you *can* write a function that returns the int of whatever shirt size you put in, or make `choices_dict` part of your `Person` object.